# Scraping page with hidden fields in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-headers, python-requests, hidden-field

I'm trying to scrap a web page with Requests. However, I always get an error message.

What I want to do:

1. In the site "http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg" I search the code 02998275000191 (this page have a Captcha)
2. The result will be displayed, and inside it I want to get the "Composição da Carteira" information. The end results I want for this code are stored in the following page:

"http://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/Sistemas/SCW/CPublica/CDA/CPublicaCDA.aspx?PK_PARTIC=20052"

(If you try to access this link the browser will redirect you to the page in step 1)

What I tried: with Firebug I observed the POST and made the following code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/Sistemas/SCW/CPublica/CDA/CPublicaCDA.aspx?PK_PARTIC=20052'

f = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

formData={
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',   
'__EVENTTARGET':'ddCOMPTC',
'__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
'__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,   
'__LASTFOCUS':'',   
'ddCOMPTC': 47126151}

#("ddCOMPTC': 47126151" I'm trying to get information in "05/2015" option)

r=requests.post(url, data=formData)
r.text
```

However I get an HTML with an error message. This one:

```
'<HTML>\r\n<HEAD>\r\n<LINK REL=\'stylesheet\' HREF=\'/SWB/estilos.css\'>\r\n</HEAD>\r\n<BODY background=\'/SWB/images/mapa/fundo_.gif\' bgproperties=\'FIXED\' class=\'BodyP\' >\r\n<center>\r\n<span class=\'TitPag\'>Erro em Página do Sistema</span>\r\n</center>\r\n<hr><br>\r\n\r\n\r\n<br>\r\n<font color="red">Ocorreu um erro de processamento no servidor.</font>\r\n<br>\r\nPor favor, entre em contato com o <a href="mailto:sistemaweb@cvm.gov.br?subject=20150801_001054963.txt" title="Suporte">suporte</a> informando o seguinte código:<br>\r\n<br>\r\n<b>20150801_001054963.txt</b>\r\n<br><br><center><a href=\'http://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/default.asp?sg_sistema=sac&dest=3\' TARGET=\'_top\' class=\'MailLink\'>Fale com a CVM</a>`enter code here`</center>\r\n</BODY>\r\n</HTML>\r\n'
```

The response I was expecting:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='/SWB/estilos.css'>
</HEAD>
<BODY background='/SWB/images/mapa/fundo_.gif' bgproperties='FIXED' class='BodyP'  leftmargin='2' >
<center>
<span class='TitPag'>Consulta a Carteiras de Fundos</span>
</center>
<hr><br>

<HTML>

<body>
<script language="javascript" src="sticky.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function AbrirDet(URL) {
        window.showModalDialog(URL,'Aplicação','center: yes; status: no; help: no; dialogWidth=300px; dialogHeight: 250px;');
    }
</script>

<form name="Form1" method="post" action="CPublicaCDA.aspx?PK_PARTIC=20052&amp;COMPTC=12%2f2014" id="Form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
// -->
</script>


<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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" />
    <p class="BodyP"><font class="Msg">Atenção:</font>  Estas informações tem por base os documentos enviados à CVM pelas Instituições Administradoras dos Fundos de Investimento e são de exclusiva responsabilidade destas. Sua divulgação pela CVM não implica na garantia da veracidade das informações prestadas ou do julgamento sobre a qualidade do fundo.</p>




    <table id="tabAtivos" class="BodyPP" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse">
    <tr style="background-color:#B4CAE0;">
        <td colspan="12"><b>Competência:</b>&nbsp;<select name="ddCOMPTC" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ddCOMPTC\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" language="javascript" id="ddCOMPTC" class="BodyPP">
            <option value="47979114">06/2015</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="47126151">05/2015</option>
            <option value="46371518">04/2015</option>
            <option value="45676450">03/2015</option>
            <option value="44914275">02/2015</option>
            <option value="44220683">01/2015</option>
            <option value="43527104">12/2014</option>
            <option value="42790168">11/2014</option>
            <option value="42117305">10/2014</option>
            <option value="41402410">09/2014</option>
            <option value="40694284">08/2014</option>
            <option value="40164360">07/2014</option>
            <option value="39544844">06/2014</option>
            <option value="38733493">05/2014</option>
            <option value="38097957">04/2014</option>
            <option value="37432596">03/2014</option>
            <option value="36929616">02/2014</option>
            <option value="36275700">01/2014</option>
            <option value="35602420">12/2013</option>
            <option value="34912766">11/2013</option>
            <option value="34336650">10/2013</option>
            <option value="33693826">09/2013</option>
            <option value="33134370">08/2013</option>
            <option value="32553998">07/2013</option>
            <option value="31897138">06/2013</option>
            <option value="31343907">05/2013</option>
            <option value="30747415">04/2013</option>
            <option value="30311074">03/2013</option>
            <option value="29611729">02/2013</option>
            <option value="29136793">01/2013</option>
            <option value="28673536">12/2012</option>
            <option value="28222978">11/2012</option>
            <option value="27828603">10/2012</option>
            <option value="27374884">09/2012</option>
            <option value="27027261">08/2012</option>
            <option value="26601832">07/2012</option>
            <option value="26072021">06/2012</option>
            <option value="25712780">05/2012</option>
            <option value="25378374">04/2012</option>
            <option value="25060291">03/2012</option>
            <option value="24690613">02/2012</option>
            <option value="24378630">01/2012</option>
            <option value="24050066">12/2011</option>
            <option value="23689471">11/2011</option>
            <option value="23380550">10/2011</option>
            <option value="23051281">09/2011</option>
            <option value="22701602">08/2011</option>
            <option value="22375318">07/2011</option>
            <option value="22042029">06/2011</option>
            <option value="21689082">05/2011</option>
            <option value="21362591">04/2011</option>
            <option value="21090383">03/2011</option>
            <option value="20738329">02/2011</option>
            <option value="20414047">01/2011</option>
            <option value="20085359">12/2010</option>
            <option value="19722649">11/2010</option>
            <option value="19462223">10/2010</option>
            <option value="19093508">09/2010</option>
            <option value="18730018">08/2010</option>
            <option value="18377523">07/2010</option>
            <option value="17974552">06/2010</option>
            <option value="17636734">05/2010</option>
            <option value="17381807">04/2010</option>
            <option value="17165626">03/2010</option>
            <option value="16848209">02/2010</option>
            <option value="16621061">01/2010</option>
            <option value="16337415">12/2009</option>
            <option value="16071991">11/2009</option>
            <option value="15829115">10/2009</option>
            <option value="15593907">09/2009</option>
            <option value="15359761">08/2009</option>
            <option value="15122648">07/2009</option>
            <option value="14859690">06/2009</option>
            <option value="14632449">05/2009</option>
            <option value="14420655">04/2009</option>
            <option value="14207002">03/2009</option>
            <option value="13963521">02/2009</option>
            <option value="13797806">01/2009</option>
            <option value="13543977">12/2008</option>
            <option value="13342530">11/2008</option>
            <option value="13048377">10/2008</option>
            <option value="12811692">09/2008</option>
            <option value="12556305">08/2008</option>
            <option value="12337609">07/2008</option>
            <option value="12077721">06/2008</option>
            <option value="11885831">05/2008</option>
            <option value="11644375">04/2008</option>
            <option value="11420340">03/2008</option>
            <option value="11233019">02/2008</option>
            <option value="11002494">01/2008</option>
            <option value="10778381">12/2007</option>
            <option value="10559863">11/2007</option>
            <option value="10370484">10/2007</option>
            <option value="10124929">09/2007</option>
            <option value="9919755">08/2007</option>
            <option value="9666652">07/2007</option>
            <option value="9423830">06/2007</option>
            <option value="9226298">05/2007</option>
            <option value="9028919">04/2007</option>
            <option value="8869643">03/2007</option>
            <option value="8665839">02/2007</option>
            <option value="8504579">01/2007</option>
            <option value="8373160">12/2006</option>
            <option value="8149177">11/2006</option>
            <option value="7990393">10/2006</option>
            <option value="7832226">09/2006</option>
            <option value="7670330">08/2006</option>
            <option value="7507103">07/2006</option>
            <option value="7351360">06/2006</option>
            <option value="7171538">05/2006</option>
            <option value="7000074">04/2006</option>
            <option value="6847369">03/2006</option>
            <option value="6686552">02/2006</option>
            <option value="6541080">01/2006</option>
            <option value="6370362">12/2005</option>
            <option value="6213740">11/2005</option>
            <option value="6063840">10/2005</option>
            <option value="5907915">09/2005</option>
            <option value="5748510">08/2005</option>
            <option value="5583310">07/2005</option>
            <option value="5417695">06/2005</option>
            <option value="5257417">05/2005</option>
            <option value="5122231">04/2005</option>
            <option value="3401412">03/2005</option>
            <option value="3213988">02/2005</option>
            <option value="2884033">01/2005</option>
            <option value="2598195">12/2004</option>
            <option value="2422312">11/2004</option>
            <option value="2257014">10/2004</option>
            <option value="2112441">09/2004</option>
            <option value="1935484">08/2004</option>
            <option value="1756309">07/2004</option>
            <option value="1600541">06/2004</option>
            <option value="1428826">05/2004</option>
            <option value="1273787">04/2004</option>
            <option value="1114970">03/2004</option>
            <option value="1065247">02/2004</option>
            <option value="1049348">01/2004</option>
            <option value="1018418">12/2003</option>
            <option value="1001870">11/2003</option>
            <option value="982543">10/2003</option>
            <option value="961820">09/2003</option>
            <option value="943902">08/2003</option>
            <option value="925811">07/2003</option>
            <option value="895982">06/2003</option>
            <option value="873549">05/2003</option>
            <option value="852918">04/2003</option>
            <option value="833004">03/2003</option>
            <option value="814866">02/2003</option>
            <option value="797716">01/2003</option>
            <option value="771557">12/2002</option>
            <option value="749858">11/2002</option>
            <option value="725565">10/2002</option>
            <option value="702378">09/2002</option>
            <option value="677030">08/2002</option>
            <option value="660474">07/2002</option>

        </select></td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#B4CAE0;">
        <td colspan="6"><B>Nome do Fundo:&nbsp;</B><span id="lbNmDenomSocial">BRADESCO FMP - FGTS  PETROBRAS</span></td><td colspan="6"><B>CNPJ:&nbsp;</B><span id="lbNrPfPj">02.998.275/0001-91</span></td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#B4CAE0;">
        <td colspan="6"><B>Administrador:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</B><span id="lbNmDenomSocialAdm">BANCO BRADESCO S.A.</span></td><td colspan="6"><B>CNPJ:&nbsp;</B><span id="lbNrPfPjAdm">60.746.948/0001-12</span></td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#B4CAE0;">
        <td colspan="12"><B>Versão:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</B><span id="lbCodVersao">3.0</span></td>
    </tr><tr id="trGraph" style="background-color:White;">
        <td colspan="12"><img id="imgPGraph" src="CDAPieChart.aspx?PPD=47126151&amp;Versao=3" border="0" /><br><br></td>
    </tr><tr id="trPL" style="background-color:#B4CAE0;">
        <td colspan="6"><B>Patrimônio Líquido do Fundo:&nbsp;</B><span id="lbPatrimLiq">R$ 205.449.147,92</span></td><td colspan="6"><b>Data de Recebimento das Informações:&nbsp;</b><span id="lbDtRegDoc">02/06/2015 22:19:51</span></td>
    </tr><tr id="trAplics" style="background-color:#C9E3F5;">
        <td colspan="12"><table id="dlAplics" class="BodyPP" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" rules="all" border="1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
                <td align="center" colspan="11"><b>Lista de Aplicações<br>Clique sobre o ativo para mais informações.</b></td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
                <td align="center" rowspan="3" style="width:30%;"><b>Ativo</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="3"><b>Classificação</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="3"><b>Empresa Ligada</b></td><td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Negócios Realizados no Mês</b></td><td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Posição Final</b></td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Vendas</b></td><td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Aquisições</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Valores</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width:7%;"><B>% Patr. Líq.</B></td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
                <td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Valor<br></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Valor<br></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Custo<br></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Mercado<br></b></td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475250')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Ações<br><b>Cod. Ativo:</b> PETR3<br><b>Dt. Ini. Vigen.:</b> 18/09/1973<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">1.650.825</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc">24.476.257,57</span></td><td align="center">247.000</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc">3.643.126,30</span></td><td align="center">11.477.314</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlPosFim">152.074.410,50</span></td><td align="center">74,02</td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475254')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Ações<br><b>Descrição:</b> PETR4<br><b>CNPJ do emissor:</b> 33.000.167/0001-01<br><b>Denominação Social do emissor: </b> PETROLEO BRASILEIRO S.A. PETROBRAS<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc">0,00</span></td><td align="center">1.437.007</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc">19.910.568,64</span></td><td align="center">4.255.962</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">52.476.011,46</span></td><td align="center">25,542</td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475253')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Disponibilidades<br><b>Descrição:</b> Disponibilidade<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfEmpLigada"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlPosFim">1.557,03</span></td><td align="center">0,001</td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475249')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Títulos Públicos<br><b>Cod. SELIC:</b> 210100<br><b>Venc.:</b> 07/09/2015<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltEmpLigada"></span></td><td align="center">88</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc">602.231,79</span></td><td align="center">270</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc">1.845.211,12</span></td><td align="center">182</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">1.247.128,69</span></td><td align="center">0,607</td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475252')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Valores a pagar<br><b>Descrição:</b> Valores a Pagar<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfEmpLigada"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlPosFim">351.942,71</span></td><td align="center">-0,171</td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
                <td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=33475251')" STYLE="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Valores a receber<br><b>Descrição:</b> Valores a Receber<br></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltTpNegoc">Para<br>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltEmpLigada"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">1.982,95</span></td><td align="center">0,001</td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
<script language="javascript">
    setup('panelDetAplic');
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
<br><br><center><a href='http://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/default.asp?sg_sistema=sac&dest=3' TARGET='_top' class='MailLink'>Fale com a CVM</a></center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is the HTML I get saying that an error occurred in the server and to please contact the administrator. (The part in r.text with the following: <font color="red">Ocorreu um erro de processamento no servidor.</font>\r\n<br>\r\nPor favor, entre em contato com o <a href="mailto:sistemaweb@cvm.gov.br)

Comment: Check r.status. Based on the html I am guessing it might be a 500, in which case your server had an internal error because it could not handle some error in your input.

Comment: The r.status_code is 200. The code get a page...but not the correct one